# Automatic mail sending with calendar invite in java

Tags: java, email

I want to send a mail which has both calendar invite as well as message body which is a html content, I tried the following code but the mail that is sent has html content as file attachment , can someone please tell me where am I wrong

```
  public class MailSender 
  {
        public static void sendMail(String emailId,String subject,String  mailBody)


{
    PropertyWriter pw=new PropertyWriter();

    try 
    {
        pw.instantiateReadObjects();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        String smtpHost=pw.getHostNameMail();
        String smtpPort=pw.getPortNumber();
        final String fromAddress=pw.getEmailSource();
        final String password=pw.getEmailPassword();

        String SSL_FACTORY="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";


        Properties props=new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",SSL_FACTORY);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","ture");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback","false");

        Session ses=Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator()
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromAddress,password);
            }
        });

        ses.setDebug(true);
        Message msg=new MimeMessage(ses);

        InternetAddress addressFrom=new InternetAddress(fromAddress);
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

        InternetAddress addressTo=new InternetAddress(emailId);
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(subject);

         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
         System.out.println(mailBody);
            StringBuffer buffer = sb.append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
                    "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN\n" +
                    "VERSION:2.0\n" +
                    "METHOD:REQUEST\n" +
                    "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
                    "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:"+emailId+"\n" +
                    "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:"+pw.getEmailSource()+"\n" +
                    "DTSTART:20051208T053000Z\n" +
                    "DTEND:20051208T060000Z\n" +
                    "LOCATION:+TH-1\n" +
                    "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" +
                    "SEQUENCE:0\n" +
                    "UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000002FF466CE3AC5010000000000000000100\n" +
                    " 000004377FE5C37984842BF9440448399EB02\n" +
                    "DTSTAMP:20051206T120102Z\n" +
                    "CATEGORIES:Session\n" +
                    "DESCRIPTION:\n\n" +
                    "SUMMARY:Session for tomorrow\n" +
                    "PRIORITY:5\n" +
                    "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" +
                    "BEGIN:VALARM\n" +
                    "TRIGGER:PT1440M\n" +
                    "ACTION:DISPLAY\n" +
                    "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n" +
                    "END:VALARM\n" +
                    "END:VEVENT\n" +
                    "END:VCALENDAR");

            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageCalendar = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Fill the message
            messageCalendar.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-  classes:calendarmessage");
            messageCalendar.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
            messageCalendar.setContent(mailBody, "BAKCHODI");
            messageCalendar.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
                    new ByteArrayDataSource(buffer.toString(), "text/calendar")));

            MimeBodyPart bc = new MimeBodyPart();
            bc.setContent(mailBody,"text/html");

            BodyPart messageBody = bc;
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();



            // Add part one
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageCalendar);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBody);

            //Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(msg);



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to have attachements ? If so what should be the attachement?

Comment: I dont want to have attachement i want to have a message body whose mime type is html.
Actually i am generating data in html tabular format, i want that to be part of mail body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simply to add the message body first like this:

```
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBody);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageCalendar);
```

Instead of this:

```
multipart.addBodyPart(messageCalendar);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBody);
```